# How to pass evt.target.value to a separate js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to send the user input value to my `voucherCheck` js file , I currently have the input as the following:

```
    <input type="text" onKeyPress={(evt) => voucherCheck(sessionId, evt.target.value)}></input>
```

This then goes through to my code that processes all prop types etc:

```
ReviewTab.propTypes = {
  session: PropTypes.shape({
    date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  consumerName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  consumerEmail: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  consumerPhonenumber: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  setReviewed: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  voucherCheck: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ReviewTab.contextTypes = {
  setTab: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({
  sessionId,
  sessions,
  consumerName: { value: consumerName },
  consumerEmail: { value: consumerEmail },
  consumerPhonenumber: { value: consumerPhonenumber },
}) => ({
  session: _.find(sessions, ({ id }) => id === sessionId),
  consumerName,
  consumerEmail,
  consumerPhonenumber,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setReviewed: setReviewedActionCreator,
  voucherCheck: sessionId => dispatch(voucherCheckActionCreator(sessionId))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(s)(ReviewTab));
```

However at this point I am confused as to how I should go about passing the `evt.target.value` data to my js file elsewhere, I can get the `sessionId` accessed in the js file but not the `evt` value, any assistance is appreciated.

```
import fetch from '../../../../core/fetch';

export default sessionId => async (dispatch, getState) => {

  console.log(sessionId);
  console.log(evt.target.value);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your mapDispatchToProps you are just passing one argument to actionCreator. You can change it to accept any number of arguments like

```
voucherCheck: (...args) => dispatch(voucherCheckActionCreator(...args))
```

and then you can receive them in the action creator like

```
export default (sessionId, value) => async (dispatch, getState) => {

  console.log(sessionId);
  console.log(value);

};
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)